# get address of Linux file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, unix

There is `fileno` to get the file descriptor of a FILE*.

How do you get the address for the FILE* given a file descriptor number, e.g. as returned from `pipe`?

[fileno](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fileno.html)
[pipe](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/251813/possible-to-customize-terminal-context-right-click-menu

Comment: What does that Ubuntu question have to do with this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [`fdopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen) function:

```
FILE * file = fdopen(fd, "r");
```

so you could use it in combination with `pipe` like this:

```
FILE * file = fdopen(pipe(..,..), "r");
```

Comment: Your second example doesn't work. The return value of [`pipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) is 0 on succes and -1 on error. You must use the values of the `pipefd` array instead.

Comment: +1: A file descriptor does not automatically have an associated FILE. A FILE typically uses auxiliary information, such as buffers for read and/or write, that is a lot of overhead if you just want to do low-level file operations using file descriptors.